# How to define a loss in Tensorflow / Keras for a dataset with multiple labels in the form of dictionary?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have a dataset that has multiple labels, and I want to define a loss that depends on the labels. The labels in the dataset are stored as a dictionary, for example:

```py
y = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices({'values': [1, 2, 3], 'symbols': [4, 5, 6]})
```

Then I want to define a loss for each label, to later make some combination of the losses. I try to define the loss like this:

```py
def model_loss(y, y_):
    return tf.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False, name='values_xent')(y['values'], y_)
```

However it gives me the following error when I fit the model:

```
TypeError: Only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), tf.newaxis (`None`) and scalar tf.int32/tf.int64 tensors are valid indices, got 'values'
```

So it seems I can not do this `y['values']`. How could I acces this values in the loss? Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

What I want to achieve is something like this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# samples
ds_x = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(np.random.randn(5, 5))

# labels
ds_y = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices({'l1': np.arange(5), 'l2':np.arange(5)})

# samples + labels
ds = tf.data.Dataset.zip((ds_x, ds_y))

# model
input_ = tf.keras.Input(shape=(5,))
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(30, activation='relu')(input_)
x1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='softmax')(x)
x2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='softmax')(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input_, outputs={'l1':x1, 'l2':x2})

# loss
def model_loss(y, y_):
    res = 3 * tf.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()(y['l1'], y_['l1'])
    res += tf.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()(y['l2'], y_['l2'])
    return res

# compile and train
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=model_loss)
model.fit(ds.batch(5), epochs=5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minute you do something that's not completely normal for Keras, I'd suggest using a [custom training loop](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_training_walkthrough). Then you can control every single step of the training process.

I did that and I didn't need to change your loss function.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

ds_x = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(np.random.randn(5, 5).astype(np.float32))

ds_y = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices({'l1': np.arange(5), 'l2':np.arange(5)})

ds = tf.data.Dataset.zip((ds_x, ds_y)).batch(2)

input_ = tf.keras.Input(shape=[5])
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(30, activation='relu')(input_)
x1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='softmax')(x)
x2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='softmax')(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input_, outputs={'l1':x1, 'l2':x2})

def model_loss(y, y_):
    res = 3 * tf.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()(y['l1'], y_['l1'])
    res += tf.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()(y['l2'], y_['l2'])
    return res

train_loss = tf.keras.metrics.Mean()
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()

for i in range(25):
    for x, y in ds:
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            out = model(x)
            loss = model_loss(y, out)
            
        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))
        train_loss(loss)
    print(f'Epoch {i} Loss: {train_loss.result():=4.4f}')
    train_loss.reset_states()
```

```
Epoch 0 Loss: 6.4170
Epoch 1 Loss: 6.3396
Epoch 2 Loss: 6.2737
Epoch 11 Loss: 5.7191
Epoch 12 Loss: 5.6608
Epoch 19 Loss: 5.2646
Epoch 24 Loss: 4.9896
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate through `y` before you use the key:

```
import tensorflow as tf

y_true = tf.data.Dataset.\
    from_tensor_slices({'symbols': tf.one_hot([0, 1, 0], depth=2)})
y_pred = tf.data.Dataset.\
    from_tensor_slices({'symbols': tf.random.uniform((3, 2), dtype=tf.float32)})

next(iter(y_true))

for a, b, in zip(y_pred, y_true):
    print(tf.losses.categorical_crossentropy(a['symbols'], b['symbols']))
```

```
tf.Tensor(6.5402465, shape=(), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(8.697783, shape=(), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(2.7932203, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

Comment: If that doesn't correspond to your problem, please make a reproducible example which causes the error

Comment: Thanks, I have posted a reproducible example. I don't see exactly how to apply this to my problem.